# ER Diagram | Group, Post, User relationship

Tags: database-diagrams, relations

I need to design an ER diagram, but I am confused in a section, more specifically how to relate the post with the groups, because I need that post contains the information of in which group I publish and that user I publish it, I have two diagrams one where the relation of post, group and user are direct, and other where the post is related by means of the table generated of the relation many to many between group and user. My question is which of these two is more recommended.

Diagram A
[image: Diagram A]

Diagram B
[image]

Answer (score 0):

the bridge table group_user between User and group is the right idea, when there is a many to many relationship

But users should be connected directly to posts like in the first image, because only pone user can have written the post-

Conclusion make a new mixed version